Intermittent "File not found." nginx php (solved)
When accessing certain paths to a web application I'm working on, I am intermittently getting a "File not found." error displaying in the browser that seems to come and go indiscriminately - refreshing the page usually works, and it seems to happen in bunches (e.g. 10 times in a row all returning the error followed by 20 times with no issue).
The error only happens when trying to access files or directories from the /run location. I'm not sure if this is because of a misconfiguration in nginx or because lots of data is getting loaded in when hitting these routes and causing other issues.
One thing I noticed was that the access log does not get logged to when I get this issue, and it does log when the the page loads as expected. I'm not sure if that's expected or not but it seemed odd to me, since the uri was entered and the server must have been hit to give a response.
I'm frankly not even sure if this is a server configuration issue or on the application level, but based on the network tab showing nothing else loading in from the page when this error occurs (the index file within /run isn't even loaded, just a 404 for whichever route I'm trying to access).
Is there anything obviously wrong in these nginx config files? Where else should I be looking so that I can rule out or narrow down the cause of the issue?
nginx.conf
user forge;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
        worker_connections 768;
        multi_accept on;
}

http {

        ##
        # Basic Settings
        ##

        sendfile on;
        tcp_nopush on;
        tcp_nodelay on;
        keepalive_timeout 65;
        types_hash_max_size 2048;
        # server_tokens off;

        server_names_hash_bucket_size 128;
        # server_name_in_redirect off;

        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type application/octet-stream;

        ##
        # SSL Settings
        ##

        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

        ##
        # Logging Settings
        ##

        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

        ##
        # Gzip Settings
        ##

        gzip on;

        # gzip_vary on;
        # gzip_proxied any;
        # gzip_comp_level 6;
        # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
        # gzip_http_version 1.1;
        # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

        ##
        # Virtual Host Configs
        ##

        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
        include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}


sites-enabled/my-website
# FORGE CONFIG (DO NOT REMOVE!)
include forge-conf/my-website.com/before/*;

log_format custom '$http_x_forwarded_for - $remote_user [$time_local] '
    '"$request" $status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
    '"$http_user_agent"';

real_ip_header X-Forwarded-For;

server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name mywebsite.com;

    if ($http_x_forwarded_proto != 'https') {
       return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }

    root /home/forge/mywebsite.com/public_html;

    # FORGE SSL (DO NOT REMOVE!)
    # ssl_certificate;
    # ssl_certificate_key;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA512:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA512:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/dhparams.pem;

    #add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";

    index index.html index.htm index.php default.htm;

    charset utf-8;

    # FORGE CONFIG (DO NOT REMOVE!)
    include forge-conf/mywebsite.com/server/*;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log custom;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/mywebsite.com-error.log error;

    error_page 404 /index.php;

    client_max_body_size 128M;
    fastcgi_read_timeout 300;


    location ~ ^/(tam/mp3|cmbx/StagedStorage)/ {
        # add_header x-test-head downloads-block;
        default_type application/octet-stream;
        add_header Content-Disposition 'attachment;';
        disable_symlinks off;
    }

    location ~ ^/(tamXf|cmbx)/ {
        # add_header x-test-head tamXf-cmbx-block;
        location ~ \.php$ {
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            include fastcgi_params;

            fastcgi_param PHP_VALUE "upload_max_filesize=0
                post_max_size=0
                max_input_time=0";
            client_max_body_size 0;
            fastcgi_read_timeout 1200;
        }
    }

    location /run {
        # Catch-all route that redirects to index.html
        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /run/index.html;

    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        # add_header x-test-head catch-all-php-block;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\.(?!well-known).* {
        deny all;
    }
}

fastcgi_params
fastcgi_param   QUERY_STRING        $query_string;
fastcgi_param   REQUEST_METHOD      $request_method;
fastcgi_param   CONTENT_TYPE        $content_type;
fastcgi_param   CONTENT_LENGTH      $content_length;
fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME     $request_filename;
fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_NAME     $fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param   REQUEST_URI     $request_uri;
fastcgi_param   DOCUMENT_URI        $document_uri;
fastcgi_param   DOCUMENT_ROOT       $document_root;
fastcgi_param   SERVER_PROTOCOL     $server_protocol;
fastcgi_param   GATEWAY_INTERFACE   CGI/1.1;
fastcgi_param   SERVER_SOFTWARE     nginx/$nginx_version;
fastcgi_param   REMOTE_ADDR     $remote_addr;
fastcgi_param   REMOTE_PORT     $remote_port;
fastcgi_param   SERVER_ADDR     $server_addr;
fastcgi_param   SERVER_PORT     $server_port;
fastcgi_param   SERVER_NAME     $server_name;
fastcgi_param   HTTPS           $https if_not_empty;
fastcgi_param   REDIRECT_STATUS     200;
fastcgi_param   HTTP_PROXY  "";


Update:
There was a catch-all block that had access logging turned off that I turned on, and still didn't see any logs being populated as a result of this error.
However, this server was one of two targets of an Elastic Load Balancer on AWS- tailing the access logs for the second server showed entries being populated right as the error was happening.

If the access log is not showing the access, the request is not reaching this server. The Nginx configuration is therefore unrelated to your problem.

It looks like there is a catch all block that is being included that has access_log set to off. I'll try changing it.
